# Setting up second router in home from primary router

Tags: wireless-router, home-networking, wifi-configuration

I am setting up a second router (Arris Surfboard SBG6700-AC) on the main floor of my home so I can get full wifi coverage while still providing Ethernet to my office and other outlets. The primary router is a Arris NVG343BQ, stuck up in a closet on the second floor, which gives terrible to no wifi downstairs(ASDRR issues abound).
When connected to the Ethernet port downstairs, the Surfboard provides internet if a Ethernet cable is used, but won't do Wifi. I beat my head against this trying IP Passthrough from the primary router to the secondary, I tried cascading the router but I am probably misconfiguring one or both routers. I am at a total loss as what to try next. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: From which port to which port is the cable connected on the routers?

Comment: Port 1 to Port 1

Comment: What I meant was are you using Wan or Lan ports?

Comment: LAN ports from the main router, with WAN Service line going into a dedicated port on it.

Comment: The Arris Surfboard SBG6700-AC is a cable modem not a router.

Comment: It's a cable modem/WiFi & 2 port Gigabit router combo